# Adding a map to a class

Tags: google-maps, dictionary

Hello I would like to add a map (static image) to a page. I will try to explain what I have done so far and what my problem is as good as I can in case someone else has the same problem in the future.

I have done the following:
1. Updated the Manifest file with permissions/API (got the API (from Google API Console) key using the SHA1 from Eclipse using Window > Preferences > Build
2. Updated the XML file of the class where the map will be added
3. Added some Java code into the classes Java file

Below is the Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.learn2develop.lapmaster"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/lapmaster_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="net.learn2develop.lapmaster.LapMasterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="Logged In"
            android:name=".UserLoggedInScreen" >
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="net.learn2develop.UserLoggedInScreen" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>        
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="Track Listing"
            android:name=".ListOfCircuits" >
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="net.learn2develop.ListOfCircuits" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>        
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="Snetterton"
            android:name=".Snetterton" >
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="net.learn2develop.Snetterton" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>        
        </activity>
        <!-- Other activities -->
        <!-- Google Play Services -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Various" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Below is the class XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Below is the class Java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class Snetterton extends Activity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.snetterton);

    SupportMapFragment map = ((SupportMapFragment)
    .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
    .getMap();
}
}
```

As you can probably guess from my code I am creating an app for race tracks. In the class called Snetterton I want to add a picture (Google maps) of Snetterton.

To get to this page the user:
1. Starts at a login screen (LapMasterActivity)
2. Is greeted with a home page (UserLoggedInScreen)
3. Goes to a page with a list of tracks (for now it is just Snetterton) (ListOFTracks)
4. When the user clicks the button for Snetterton it takes them to the Snetterton class' page where I would like the map. (Snetterton).

In my code only ((SupportMapFragment) is underlined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answered this myself (eventually):

Code I used is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>


public class TopGear extends Activity
{   
private GoogleMap aMap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.top_gear);

    aMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    aMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);

    LatLng topGearTrack = new LatLng(51.116492, -0.541767);

    aMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    aMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(topGearTrack, 15));

    aMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Top Gear")
            .snippet("Welcome to the famous Top Gear circuit.")
            .position(topGearTrack));

    aMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

public void setUpMapIfNeeded() 
{
    //Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (aMap == null) 
    {
        aMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                            .getMap();
    //Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
    if (aMap != null) 
    {
        //The Map is verified. It is now safe to manipulate the map.
        }
    }
}
}
```